# how to clear return stack buffer in x86 or x64

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, coroutine

Now i am writing a coroutines library in c++ and assemble. But the coroutines switching breaks the accuracy of “return stack buffer” (see http://www.agner.org/optimize/microarchitecture.pdf p.36) in x86/x64, because during the switching we will change stack pointer register and return (to another coroutine), so all the content in the return stack buffer is wrong.

Excepting call a deep enough(the size of the return stack buffer is 16 in modern x64 cpu) function and return to clear the return stack buffer(then old content are all popped out),  can we **explicit** clear (or backup) the return stack buffer via any instructions? Or can we pre-load some new instructions to avoid cpu pre-load the instructions after the address in return stack buffer?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: There's no need to. The RET instructions won't be predicted correctly either way. Even making a bunch of nested calls and returning from them won't help as the return stack buffer is very likely implemented in the simplest and cheapest way: a ring buffer with single index that marks both the start and end of the stack. In other words it has no empty state and RET instructions are always predicted using it. I wouldn't worry about it, since you're paying the penalty that normal context switches have to pay.

Comment: I don't know your exact implementation, but it seems like you could avoid this by using a plain old indirect branch instead of a return.

Comment: @harold you just delay the penalty.

Comment: @RossRidge I think if Intel real implements a stack buffer and stop prediction unless the stack is empty when RET,  it will simply improve the performance of the predictor in pipeline.

Comment: @RossRidge most of the introduction says the predictor is highly accurate..

Comment: No, control transfer instructions are always predicted. They either use a dynamic prediction method like the return stack, or they use a static method, like predicting the following instruction will be executed. There's no advantage to not predicting RET instructions, when RET instruction is retired and the prediction turns out to be wrong the pipeline is completely empty, the same state it would be in if the CPU simply stalled waiting for the RET instruction to retire.

Comment: @YuanZhu why? there is no call/ret in my suggestion, so no possibility of trashing the predictor. Of course indirect jumps are not predicted well either, but that's a local problem.